# Configuring HTML Tidy to indent tags and nothing else in Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++, configure, tidy

All I want HTMLTidy to do is indent my HTML document's tags, but it currently also changes the `doctype`, adds an `xmlns` attribute to the `html` tag, changes `<br />` tags, and probably does some other stuff.

How do I make it so that HTMLTidy in Notepad++ only performs indentation when I select **TextFX → TextFX HTML Tidy → TiDy Clean Document-nowrap**?

Answer (score 3):

There's a file called `HTMLTIDY.CFG` in `<NPPInstallDir>plugins\Config\tidy` that configures the Tidy operation. From what you said, I think all you'd have to do is remove (or comment out with ';') everything but the indent options, i.e.

```
indent: yes
indent-spaces: 2
```

Comment: I tried that, and it still added the unwanted content, including some weird looking stuff around the stuff in between <style></style> and an extra meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the XML plugin for Notepad++.  It has a "pretty print" feature that will probably work on HTML.

Comment: I tried installing it and an error message came up, saying the version wasn't compatible with my version of Notepad++. My version is Unicode. I think "XML Tools" only comes in ANSI.

Comment: I've seen that before.  I would imagine if you uninstalled and then re-installed the new version of Notepad++ then it would work. I've installed it dozens of times myself.